How to add a language switching button/Dropdown in react-i18next?
I'm using https://github.com/i18next/next-app-dir-i18next-example-ts
I added a blank navigation bar and wanted to add a switch language button to switch languages ​​and stay on the current page.
I tried to look at the code of Footer. It is a bit complicated and difficult for me as a newbie to understand.
Is there some easy way to set this up? Thanks
